# Calendar application for Windows Phone 8 with better views

Tags: calendar, windows-phone

Is there any calendar application for Windows Phone 8 which has better calendar views than out-of-the-box one?  I especially mean week view and month view.

I remember out-of-the-box calendar in Windows Mobile 6.x which had detailed and useful views of day and week resembling desktop Outlook calendar views.

Also recognizing color categories of calendar items as defined in Outlook (work, traveling, meeting, vacation etc.) would be greatly welcome, too.

(I'm wondering whether Microsoft will return *normal* calendar into Windows Phone some day or whether it is gone forever. Current one is unusable in many aspects.)